# Pytorch: why logging fails in DDP?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, python-multiprocessing, python-logging

I would like to use logging in one of the processes managed by Distributed Data Parallel. However, logging print nothing in the following codes (the codes are derived from [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html)):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, logging
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

import torch

def setup(rank, world_size):
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '12355'

    # Initialize the process group.
    dist.init_process_group('NCCL', rank=rank, world_size=world_size)


def cleanup():
    dist.destroy_process_group()


class ToyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ToyModel, self).__init__()
        self.net1 = nn.Linear(10, 10)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.net2 = nn.Linear(10, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.net2(self.relu(self.net1(x)))


def demo_basic(rank, world_size):
    setup(rank, world_size)

    if rank == 0:
        logger = logging.getLogger('train')
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.info(f'Running DPP on rank={rank}.')

    # Create model and move it to GPU.
    model = ToyModel().to(rank)
    ddp_model = DDP(model, device_ids=[rank])

    loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(ddp_model.parameters(), lr=0.001)  # optimizer takes DDP model.

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    inputs = torch.randn(20, 10)  # .to(rank)

    outputs = ddp_model(inputs)

    labels = torch.randn(20, 5).to(rank)
    loss_fn(outputs, labels).backward()

    optimizer.step()

    cleanup()


def run_demo(demo_func, world_size):
    mp.spawn(
        demo_func,
        args=(world_size,),
        nprocs=world_size,
        join=True
    )


def main():
    run_demo(demo_basic, 4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, when I uncomment the 4th line, the logging works. May I know the reason and how to fix the bug please?

Comment: Unless I miscounted, the 6th line is empty - I guess you meant 4th?

Comment: @Xtrem532 Thanks for pointing out. Correct now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE

Let's briefly review how loggers in the `logging` module work.

Loggers are organized in a tree structure, i.e. every logger has a unique `parent` logger. By default, it will be the `root` logger, while the `root` logger doesn't have a parent logger.

When you call `Logger.info` method (ignore level checking here for simplicity) on a logger, the logger iterates all of its `handlers` and let them handle the current record, e.g. handlers can be StreamHandler which can print to stdout, or FileHandler which prints to some file). After all of the handlers of current logger finish their jobs, the record will be given to its parent logger and, the parent logger handles the record in the same way, i.e. iterates all handlers of parent logger and lets them handle the record, finnally passes the record to "grandparent". This procedure continues until reaching the root of current loggers' tree, which doesn't have a parent.

Check the implementation below or [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1645):

```py
def callHandlers(self, record):
    c = self
    found = 0
    while c:
        for hdlr in c.handlers:
            found = found + 1
            if record.levelno >= hdlr.level:
                hdlr.handle(record)
        if not c.propagate:
            c = None    #break out
        else:
            c = c.parent
```

So in your case, you didn't specify any handler for the `train` logger. When you uncomment the 6th line, i.e. by calling `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`, a `StreamHandler` is created for the `root` logger. Though there isn't any handler for the `train` logger, there is a `StreamHandler` for its parent i.e. the `root` logger, which prints anything you see actually, while `train` logger print nothing in this case. When the 6th line in commented, even one `StreamHandler` is not created for the `root` handler, so in this case nothing is printed. So In fact the issue has nothing to do with DDP.

By the way, the reason I can't reproduce your issue at first is because I use PyTorch 1.8, where `logging.info` will be called during the execution of `dist.init_process_group` for backends other than MPI, which implicitly calls `basicConfig`, creates a `StreamHandler` for the root logger and seems to print message as expected.

======================================================================

One possible reason: Because during the execution of `dist.init_process_group`, it will call `_store_based_barrier`, which finnaly will call `logging.info` (see the source code [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py#L191)). So if you call `logging.basicConfig` before you call `dist.init_process_group`, it will be initialized in advance which makes the root logger ignore all levels of log.

This is not the case in your code because `logging.basicConfig` is at the top of the file, which will be executed at frist before `dist.init_process_group`. Actually I'm able to run the code you provide, after filling the missing imports such as `nn` and `dist` though, with logging works normally. Maybe you attempted to reduce the code to reproduce the issue, but circumvent the real issue behind unconsciously? Could you double check if this resolves your issue?

Comment: Hi, the rest import statements were removed from 6th line because of the restriction of the stackoverflow. Except those, nothing else was missing. I tried the above code on torch 1.7 but the `logging` does not work.

Comment: BTW, I have left a similar question [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-do-we-have-to-create-logger-in-process-for-correct-logging-in-ddp/102164). I am unfamiliar with logging and multi-processes. I would be rather grateful if you figure it out. :D

Comment: @Tengerye Check my updates and I think it can answer your another question too now.

Comment: I can understand the first question from your answer. But, why the outputs are different between logger creation in or out of individual process? (example is provided [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-do-we-have-to-create-logger-in-process-for-correct-logging-in-ddp/102164/3?u=tengerye))

Answer (score 1):

I will clarify what I found for those who are unfamiliar with python's logging mechanism like me.

The problem is not because of Pytorch and any third party package could trigger such this phenomenon. The reason is the `logging` is singleton. Any modification to the `basicConfig` affects both our code and codes from the third-party.

My current solution is to create a module level logger and share it across different modules.

Comment: Could you please provide a code example of your solution, thanks!